# How to prove $\operatorname{Id}-K$ is a proper map when $K$ is a $C^1$ compact operator?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, operator-theory

Assume $X$ is a Banach space, $\Omega \subseteq X$ is an open set, $K\in {C}^{1}( \overline{\Omega}, X)$ is a nonlinear compact map, Is $\operatorname{Id}-K$ a proper map? I think maybe it has something to do with the spectrum of the compact operator. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: In the case $X = \Omega = \mathbb{R}$, the mapping $K = Id$ is compact, but $Id - K$ is not proper.

Comment: yeah, I agree with you.

Comment: Is there any sufficient condition？

Comment: A sufficient condition is of course that $K(\Omega)$ is relatively compact. If you use the usual definition of compact map (maps bounded sets into relatively compact sets), it is thus sufficient that $\Omega$ is bounded,

Comment: Another often-used sufficient condition for unbounded $\Omega$ is that $\lVert K(x)\rVert/\lVert x\rVert\to\infty$ as $\lVert x\rVert\to\infty$ (which implies that $(I-K)^{-1}(B)$ is bounded for bounded $B$).

Comment: Thank you very much! @MartinVäth